# Typescript class implements interface simplify

Tags: typescript

I'm creating my custom class AxiosError, but I thought the code seems to be redundant.

```
  //types.ts

  export interface IAxiosRequest{}
  export interface IAxiosResponse{}

  export interface IAxiosError{
    message:string
    request:IAxiosRequest
    response:IAxiosResponse
  }
```

```
  // error.ts

  import {AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse, IAxiosError} from 'path/to/type.ts'

  export class AxiosError extends Error implements IAxiosError {
      isAxiosError = true
      request: AxiosRequest
      response: AxiosResponse
      constructor(params:IAxiosError){
         super(params.message)
         const {request,response} = params
         this.request = request
         this.response = response
         Object.setPrototypeOf(this, AxiosError.prototype)
      }
  }

  export function createdError(params:IAxiosError){
     return new AxiosError(params)
  }
```

I thought if one class implements some interface, there is no need to illustrate all the properties defined in the interface. I mean, if the interface has many properties, it is annoying 'cause you have to illustrate all the properties in the class again

so I hope the error.ts should be

```
  import { IAxiosError} from 'path/to/type.ts'

  export class AxiosError extends Error implements IAxiosError {
      isAxiosError = true
      constructor(params:IAxiosError){
         super(params.message)
         const {request,response} = params
         this.request = request
         this.response = response
         Object.setPrototypeOf(this, AxiosError.prototype)
      }
  }

  export function createdError(params:IAxiosError){
     return new AxiosError(params)
  }
```

**but I got error. : property doesn't exist on type AxiosError**

PS:
I don't wanna use separate function parameters, if so when I invoke a function, I have to notice the **order** of the parameters

```
 export class AxiosError extends Error implements IAxiosError {
   constructor(message:string,public request:AxiosRequest,public response:AxiosResponse){
     super(message)
     Object.setPrototypeOf(this, AxiosError.prototype)
   }
 }

 export function createError(message:string,request:AxiosRequest,response:AxiosResponse){
    return new AxiosError(message,request,response)
 }
```

is there a better solution?

Comment: What you want probably requires turning IAxiosError into a class (AxiosErrorBase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a longstanding open issue; see [microsoft/TypeScript#10570](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10570).  Some fixes for this had been attempted before but they had some bad consequences for existing real-world code.

Currently, an `implements` clause just checks whether or not the class conforms to the interface; it doesn't contextually type the class in any way.  Also note that TypeScript's type system is structural and not nominal, so "`implements XXX`" isn't even necessary:

```
interface Foo { a: string, b: number }
function acceptFoo(foo: Foo) { }

class GoodFooExplicit implements Foo { a = ""; b = 1 } // okay
acceptFoo(new GoodFooExplicit()); // okay

class GoodFooImplicit { a = ""; b = 1 }
acceptFoo(new GoodFooImplicit()); // okay

class BadFooExplicit implements Foo { a = ""; } // error
acceptFoo(new BadFooExplicit()); // error

class BadFooImplicit { a = "" }
acceptFoo(new BadFooImplicit()); // error
```

In the above, a `GoodFooImplicit` is accepted by `acceptFoo()` despite not being declared as `implements Foo`.  And, for that matter, a `BadFooExplicit` is rejected by `acceptFoo()` despite being declared as `implements Foo`.  Currently, the only use of `implements XXX` is to provide an early warning if an instance of the class would not be assignable to the interface, so you can catch the error at the class declaration (as in `BadFooExplicit`) instead of having to wait until the first attempt to use an instance as  if it were assignable to the interface.

---

So, what can be done?  Other than going to the above linked issue and giving it a , or giving up, the best I can think of is to use a helper function to generate a parent class that already implements whatever type you're looking for.  For example:

```
class AxiosError extends ClassFor<IAxiosError>().mixParent(Error) {
  isAxiosError = true
  constructor(params: IAxiosError) {
    super(params, params.message);
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, AxiosError.prototype)
  }
}
```

In the above, `ClassFor<IAxiosError>()` would be a class constructor which takes a single parameter of type `IAxiosError` and returns an instance of `IAxiosError`. And `ClassFor<IAxiosError>().mixParent(Error)` is a class constructor which takes an `IAxiosError` as a first parameter, and then expects the constructor arguments for the `Error` class, and returns an instance of `IAxiosError` that is also an `instanceof Error`.

Because that first argument needs to be an `IAxiosError`, I refactored the implementaton of your constructor so that it calls `super(params, params.message)`.

And you don't need to write `implements IAxiosError`, because `extends ClassFor<IAxiosError>().mixParent(Error)` already establishes that.

My implementation of `ClassFor` looks like this:

```
function ClassFor<T extends object>() {
  function classWithParent<A extends any[], P extends object>(parent: new (...a: A) => P) {
    return class extends (parent as any) {
      constructor(obj: T, ...parentArgs: any[]) {
        super(...parentArgs);
        Object.assign(this, obj);
      }
    } as new (obj: T, ...a: A) => (T & P)
  }
  return Object.assign(classWithParent(class { }), {
    mixParent<A extends any[], P extends object>(parent: new (...a: A) => P) {
      return classWithParent(parent);
    }
  })
}
```

That might look complicated, but the idea is that it returns a class expression and we use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to silence the compiler when it can't verify what we're doing.  All the type assertions are confined to that function, though, so you could presumably stick `ClassFor` in a library somewhere and just use it.

Anyway, you can verify that it works using the playground link at the bottom.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnJwBcyAzmFKAOYA0+yARiSAK4C2D0uAvrjCyARhg6EIQRIADmAzoAFDEwlZAShzJeuBABs4pUsgDimACayAogA9J24AmBhkwNjYhsI4A7PVxkAXmQAIkCAbkZ-ZABGDWQAeljkdABrOABPXEQpGUw5EAgAdyNTC2tbezA5FRUw+MSU9K1dfSL0M0wASRcyhx8I4LCGCOjeTIhpWVyClrb0Tps7B0rquITktNxGvQMAITgZq3nypy63DzAvTF6A-pja6Ch0KAyJMez5PMLd-dKFiqqahL3R4bHRbZBfWRzbqObCEPqBDTPLITD7gvaQrq-JYA5BAp4bXCgSCwRAodoAQUsIlIACUIABHFgQcjqXhE6DwJDIClU9C05mSUSkFCwzTsklcnnU8xQB5QHD0dz6OBUCAkciUEBUehQBlM8gkKV8umM5lgHUCoVq7mU6l00iCkDCngbfiCYSiZAAYSapAwUAAPAAVXGWSAgEwGdAMABWECEAD5KgqCG6hCIxKD9AB1BwACwACnBdeAA+TQ+HI4QQKkANoAXRoyALFY8VejccTckkxbOzCmcgAdMPiMhyWo-Anm2o8AQCLqwCwoJnfa2IwZu73wIQDHAazP6HPkAghRQWEJHnIOyQg03h4OeyWwOSoFRSCQ93X6wej0fSCxJGgIdh0fM4XzfapD1-AB5WN4zAQctmAKgQDkMA82AUgmw7SDf0RI9uB3ZBUSvWMbzvEcSHHfwpzkEMADJp3oXh5wgRdl2QWDOwQpCULkLNSFzdCiyffjV1FFQm1nOc2GASwRLOMs1yrT8GybFsIDDNsozgrtQPAftCmAxCqInKcCx-X8FyXFctiEwstwqfSwFwucWI0FQXU2ZpbT5GU5WUgwfS2f0AyNUh-MeJMVEHWT5McuRIqgSzMN8iLZUeCIzwgegTydM8LygTcoDgNh3xtXl0rlSyCH-QCisfUqsOQRqyti5lSBVCBXIILj4MHYUwALB4wHQMBUkA6CYDQjDmrSpKHxGsaJu65ivLTD1M11OBIBMJLiqaw15oy5KU2QayONRY65QOsrPM0DYgA)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm new to Typescript so maybe my question looks like weird.  XD